# Is it better to use getters setters in mobile application?

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me

I need to know that what is better to use getter setter or use public instance variable  in mobile development

Comment: This has very little to do with an app being "mobile". It is a design choice, and in that a way too broad question. Read up on (for instance) OOP, and check out the what and why of getters/setters and public variables. If you're not familiar with them, the short answer might be: it doesn't matter, because you're not loosing too much efficienty either way, but I'm a bit worried about how your design comes along.

Comment: @Nanne I think access of method take more memory compare to  access  instance variable directly and memory management is very important in mobile

Comment: @DhiralPandya, this is a general question hence you will get general anwser. Please read [What kind of questions should I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application context. If you want to encapsulate properties of an object, it's often better to use getters and setters. However if you just want to store a constant or default value, use an instance variable (or field).

Comment: and what about multi-threading?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set) recommends against the use of *iternal* getters and setters.

> It's reasonable to follow common object-oriented programming practices
>   and have getters and setters in the public interface, but within a
>   class you should always access fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the using of the setters/getters and public variables of course should be avoided in any type of application because setters and getters may broke the valid state of the object. In case you need a serialization in your application I would like to suggest to use Memnto design pattern.